# Reorder ListView items: Event and Drag/Drop

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

My page contains two ListView elements, ListA and ListB. You can copy items (objects) from ListA to ListB by use of simple drag and drop. For that I use the Lists' *DragItemsStarting* and *Drop* events. That works just fine. Now you can reorder the items in ListB. All required properties are set (reorder, drag and drop) and this works as well.

But now I want to react on the resorting, but I didn't find an event I could listen to. So I thought it might be possible to use the drag/drop events on the same list to get to know when the user has changed the psoition of an item.

So how can I recognize that the items of ListB have been reorderd?

My code (with the drag and drop approach):

```
private void ListB_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e) {
            var item = ((FeedItem)e.Items[0]);
            e.Data.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
            e.Data.SetDataProvider("FeedItem", request => request.SetData(item));
        }

private async void ListB_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
            DataPackageView view = e.Data.GetView();
            if (view.Contains("FeedItem") && view.RequestedOperation == DataPackageOperation.Copy) {
                //item from ListA 
            }
            if (view.Contains("FeedItem") && view.RequestedOperation == DataPackageOperation.Move) {
                //item from ListB
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem solved :)

To use drag and drop on the same UI element (in this case a ListView) you need to disable the *CanReorderItems* option. Then the code I provided above will work.

```
ListB.CanReorderItems = false;
```

But when you wish to keep the option to reorder the items in ListB (actually my original question) you can subscribe to the follwoing event:

```
view.VectorChanged += viewVectorChanged;

...

private void viewVectorChanged(Windows.Foundation.Collections.IObservableVector<object> sender, Windows.Foundation.Collections.IVectorChangedEventArgs @event) {

}
```

Since my list is bound to a CollectionViewSource this works fine for me. Otherwise ListView should have a similar event that you could subscribe.

Comment: interesting. I have an `ObservableCollection` and just subscribed to the `CollectionChanging` event. But I did need to leave `CanReorderItems=True`. The answer on this post has it all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388867/xaml-c-what-event-fires-after-reordering-a-gridview/16446241#16446241